# Sorting a list<T> by index using an array

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I'm having problems sorting a list by index using an array as the source of the sort.

Assume there are 5 records set to my class

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
     int[] myInt {2,1,0,3,4}
     List<Tests> myTests = new List<Tests>; 

     //this part doesn't work

     for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
         myInt[i] = myTests[i];
         }
     myTests.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", i.id, i.myString));
    }
}
```

My Class definition

```
class Tests
{
     public int iD {get; set;}
     public string myString {get; set;}

     public Tests (int iD, string myString)
    {
       this.iD = iD;
       this.myString = myString
    }
{
```

What I would like to see come out

```
     record 2
     record 1
     record 0
     record 3
     record 4
```

I tried using the sort function for lists but I couldn't find any examples that used an array as the sort criteria so I'm kind of lost. I appreciate any help offered.

Comment: `List<Tests> myTests = new List<Tests>;` won't compile. Did you mean `new List<Tests>();` or `new List<Tests>(myInt);`?

Comment: Can you give us a more complicated example? Your example gives the same output whether you interpret `myInt[i]` as "the position in the list I want the `i`th element to end up in" or "the original position of the element which I want to place in position `i` in the output" (i.e. `myInt[0] = 2` - does this say "put record 2 in position 0" or "fill position 2 with record 0"?)

Comment: It would be a lot easier to answer your questions if you posted code that compiled, or match your question more closely.

Comment: Sorry I, was having problems with the code compiling in the first place that is why I was here.  But, I have realized what I was doing wrong and why it wasn't working thanks to Rawlings comments.  However I have realized an easier and probably a more performant way just to simply do a LINQ query on the original records rather than rearranging the objects that represent them.  I appreciate everyone's help, Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head, something like this should do the trick:

```
var sortedTests = myInt
    .Select((x,index) => new {test = myTests[x], sortIndex = index})
    .OrderBy(x => x.sortIndex)
    .Select(x => x.test)
    .ToList()
```

Hmm. In fact, with Linq-to-objects it's somewhat easier:

```
var sortedTests = myInt
    .Select(x => myTests[x])
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Or possibly `.Select((index, x)...` depending on which way around OP wants this to work. (Note that, in this example, the `OrderBy` is unnecessary as the `sortIndex` values are already in order.)

Comment: @Rawling Indeed... I added a considerably simpler version!

Comment: Thank you, I actually couldn't get your code to work, but it pointed me into the right direction.  I ended up just doing a LINQ Query using the array as the search values.  I appreciate your help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the values of myTests to another List

```
List<Tests> newTests = new List<Tests>();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    newTests.Add(myTests[myInt[i]]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First:**

You can't use `myList[i]` unless you've created an item of the list in position `i`.

**Second:**

You're not calling the `Tests` constructor to create a new `Tests` object

**Third:**

You're assigning to `myInt[i]` an empty reference `myTests[i]`

You should have something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    myTests.Add(new Tests(i, "foo"))

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your provided code is kind of vague, so I cooked up a couple of different scenarios.
1. Creating based on index.
2. Sorting based on index.

Paste it into your IDE and it will work.

```
 class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      int[] myInt = new[] { 2, 1, 0, 3, 4 };

      // there is nothing to sort at this time, but this is how I would make a new list matching your index....
      var myTests = (from x in myInt select new Tests(x, "whatever")).ToList();

      myTests.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", i.iD, i.myString));


      // So assuming that you are starting with an unsorted list....
      // We create and priont one....
      myTests = new List<Tests>();
      for (int i = 0; i < myInt.Length; i++)
      {
        myTests.Add(new Tests(i, "number " + i));
      }

      Console.WriteLine("unsorted ==");
      myTests.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", i.iD, i.myString));

      // And this will perform the sort based on your criteria.
      var sorted = (from x in myInt
                    from y in myTests
                    where y.iD == x
                    select y).ToList();

      // And output the results to prove it.
      Console.WriteLine("sorted ==");
      sorted.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", i.iD, i.myString));

      Console.Read();
    }
  }
```